# How to execute procedure periodically (due date and time)?

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a record in a table, and this record has a "DATETIME" column; It is a DUE DATE and TIME. Whenever the server date reaches that date and time, it should notify the user (execute procedure that sends email notification for example, to the corresponding user). How would I do that? Some sites mentioned Windows Service scheduling, and others mentioned Maintenance Job.

Can you please suggest the best solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to regularly poll the table somehow, from a client, windows service or SQL Server Agent. Of course, you don't know if it will be picked up or picked up twice: it is possible

I'd consider creating a SQL Server Agent job when the row is inserted to pick this up if you don't have too many (for managability rather then any upper limit)

Comment: Interesting idea. Do you have an idea about the practical  maximum number of agent jobs?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: @job_id is uniqueidentifier so limitless possibly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx SSRS uses SQL Server Agent for subscriptions and I can imagine larger SSRS installs having a truck load of jobs...

Answer (score 1):

If you have to show notification to user for starting service than you can use **Window services** , which notify user to start the script to send mail by triggring click of button or some event..
[Simple Windows Service which sends auto Email alerts](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WIndows_Service.aspx)

If you want to send email to users without notifying admin on perticular date time than you should go for the SQL JOBS which do work for you. 
[SQL Server jobs](http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/sql-server-jobs.html)